# Datetimepicker (EONASDAN) sends selection as epoch timestamp nearest minute rounded

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I would like to go with Eonasdan datetime picker library. (v. `4.17.47`)

I need to include into bootstrap template a simple form (GET method) that will allow user to pickup a date and time.

The time selection must have 1 minute granularity.

When submit button is clicked I would like the user selection to be sent out as an epoch format.

In my example below, epoch format is indeed being sent but extra seconds are added to the timestamp and I would like to avoid that, this must be due to `onchange` function.

How could I get the epoch timestamp value being the real mirror of user selection rounded at the nearest minute?

http://jsfiddle.net/lcoulon/ze2x8358/

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
  locale: 'fr',
});

// Sends epoch (unix time) into epoch-start-time form
$('#datetimepicker1').on(`dp.change`, X => $('#epoch-start-time').val(X.date.unix()));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use momentjs [`startOf`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/) passing `'minute'` as *granularity* parameter

> ```
> moment().startOf('minute');  // set to now, but with 0 seconds and 0 milliseconds
> ```

Here a working sample:

```js
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
  locale: 'fr'
});
          
// Sends epoch (unix time) into epoch-start-time form
$('#datetimepicker1').on(`dp.change`, X =>
$('#epoch-start-time').val(X.date.startOf('minute').unix()));
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" style="margin:50px;">
  <h4>EOSNASDAN Bootstrap Datetime Picker</h4>
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <form class="form-horizontal" method="GET"> 
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group date col-md-5" data-date="2017-01-01T12:00:00Z" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd hh" data-link-field="epoch-start-time" id="datetimepicker1">  
            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <input id="epoch-start-time" name="epoch" type="hidden"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" type="submit">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works perfectly now, many thanks.        However i noticed that EONASDAN datetimepicker is not totaly compatible with Bootstrap v4, i may consider to roll back to bootstrap v3 to  get the form working properly.

Comment: Unfortunately, as you said, eonasdan datetimepicker is not fully compatible with bootstrap 4, see [here](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/1377) to get some info about how to fix some incompatibilites.